# Rewards in reinforcement learning for minimization problem

Tags: reinforcement-learning, extreme-value

I am new to ML/DL/RL. I am looking to solve the classic travelling salesman problem (TSP), where the salesman has to visit all cities only once and finding the smallest path to do that (minimize travelling distance).

The Q learning method is well defined for maximizing reward (maximization problem). Can I give the reward as *negative* of distance to make it solve minimization problem as described above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I give the reward as negative of distance to make it solve minimization problem as described above?

Yes. There is usually no mathematical difference between formulating a problem to minimise cost or maximise reward other than the changes in sign.

In fact you can do it in two ways:

- You can use negative cost as the reward, $r = -c$ and use Q learning as normal
- You can work directly with cost. The greedy policy takes the minimum predicted future cost, plus change the Bellman optimality equation, ending up with the update rule for Q learning as $Q(s_t, a_t) \leftarrow Q(s_t, a_t) + \alpha(c_{t+1} + \text{min}_{a'}[ Q(s_{t+1}, a') ] - Q(s_t, a_t))$. This simply swaps $c$ for $r$ and $\text{min}$ for $\text{max}$ in the standard Q update rule, and same would apply to other update rules such as n-step Q learning etc.

Probably the first option, reward is negative cost, is the simplest change to make if you want to follow existing tutorials or use existing software frameworks.